# What is the difference between constrained vs unconstrained type parameters in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

I am following a tutorial about generics in typescript and came across this

```
function marge<T, U>(objA: T, objB: U) {
  return Object.assign(objA, objB);
}

const mergeObject = marge({ fname: "Saiki" }, { lname: "Kusuo" });

console.log(mergeObject.fname);

//app.ts(19, 16): This type parameter might need an `extends {}` constraint.
//app.ts(19, 16): This type parameter might need an `extends object` constraint.


The problem is solved by marge<T extends object, U>(objA: T, objB: U)
```

which led me to this

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48468

Now you can't assign a unconstrained type parameter T to T extends {} or T extends object.

So I was wondering what are unconstrained type parameter and constrained type parameters

Comment: The link you posted must have been fixed,  as you don't always need an unconstrained type, as long as the Typescript compiler can infer the Type, it will be fine too.  Your version will of course fail, as you have not giving the compiler any hint on the type of T or U, so it can't guarantee that `.assign` exists on T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: `extends SOMETHING` is used to ensure the input has some properties / shapes.

---

If type `T` is not constrained, that means the follows is valid:

```
marge(undefined, { lname: "Kusuo" })
marge(1, { lname: "Kusuo" })
marge("hello", { lname: "Kusuo" })
```

However, it does not make sense or will throw errors.

---

On the other hand, if it is constrained, it will filter out those invalid parameter. Like the following example:

```
function printLength<T extends string>(s: T) {
  console.log(s.length)
}
```

If `extends string` got removed, the complier will complain about "no `length`" issues, because in that case, we didn't ensure the input has a `length` (is a string)